# Two simultaneous overlay with different hyperlinks on images in jQuery Kwicks slider

Tags: jquery, css

I have used jQuery ready slider by: http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks

I now need to put overlay on these slides.
When the slides are un-stretched different overlay. Which is shown in the visible part of the slide.
And later when a particular slide stretches out the previous overlay (of that particular slide) fades out and now, I need two caption overlays , one at the top and one at the bottom appear on the open slide and both of these having different hyperlink..

I have put my HTML, CSS and JQuery of Kwicks here: http://jsfiddle.net/swati/E3fJG/

And current condition of my page is: http://dental2.estheticdentalcare.co.in/HTMLPage.htm

Comment: Your jsfiddle was broken - updated version here: http://jsfiddle.net/qyXqZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've had a quick play and have altered the Kwicks plugin to add classes of *overlay1* to normal (unopened) panels, and to change this class to *overlay2* when the panel is fully expanded:

http://jsfiddle.net/3xeUt/11/

You'll see that the panels have a black border when they're closed, and a red border when they're opened.

It's up to you to add the relevant html/CSS to your code to get the overlays working... ;)